# How to stop React Navigation Progressive Web App URL query params being removed from the URL?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, progressive-web-apps, url-parameters

I'm running into an issue where URL query params are being removed from my production URL (but are working when I test them on localhost). I'm building a react native progressive web app and am using React Navigation.

This article from React Navigation seems to suggest that query params should be automatically parsed into Screen params: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/#passing-params.

So navigating to https://www.website.com/purchaseConfirmation?sessionId=123&utm_source=yay&utm_campaign=wow should pass in the screen params { sessionId: 123, utm_source: 'yay', and utm_campaign 'wow' }

But it removes the screen params from the URL. This does not happen when testing it on localhost (everything works as expected on localhost). Any hunches on what might be going on?

Thanks so much!

More code details:

My NavigationContainer linkingConfig is:

```
const config = {
  screens: {
    FinancialPlanScreen: 'financialPlan',
    FinancialPlanPurchaseConfirmationScreen: 'purchaseConfirmation'
    ...
  }
}

const linking = {
  prefixes: [], // Prefixes are not needed for Web. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/#prefixes
  config
}
```

and the App is structured like:

```
export type AppStackParamList = {
  FinancialPlanScreen: {
    utm_source?: string
    utm_campaign?: string
  }
  FinancialPlanPurchaseConfirmationScreen: {
    sessionId: string
    utm_source?: string
    utm_campaign?: string
  }
}

const AppStack = createNativeStackNavigator<AppStackParamList>()

export default function App (): JSX.Element {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    PublicSans_400Regular,
    PublicSans_700Bold,
    PublicSans_400Regular_Italic,
    PublicSans_700Bold_Italic
  })

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <View style={appStyle.outerContainer} />
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      linking={linking}
      documentTitle={{
        enabled: false
      }}
    >
      <AppStack.Navigator>
        <AppStack.Screen
          name="FinancialPlanScreen"
          component={FinancialPlanScreen}
          options={{
            headerShown: false
          }}
        />
        <AppStack.Screen
          name="FinancialPlanPurchaseConfirmationScreen"
          component={FinancialPlanPurchaseConfirmationScreen}
          options={{
            headerShown: false
          }}
        />
        ...
      </AppStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```